# kibana/elasticsearch advanced query

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am sending events with logstash to an elasticsearch database. An event is structured like this:

```
timestamp:2014-04-04 12:00:00 name:'leo'  time:10
timestamp:2014-04-04 12:00:30 name:'john' time:15
...
...
```

In the Kibana interface, I am able to display some graphs; for example, the mean time of the timestamp.

Since logstash is continuously sending events, I would like to display the latest event sent in real time. Is it possible to write a query which will only return the latest event, using the timestamp field? I don't want to touch Kibana's "time filter"

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see the latest entry is to sort by timestamp, descending, in the 'Events' section of the Kibana interface. If you really only wanted to see one result, you could adjust the paging settings to only return one page consisting of one entry, and set the 'Auto-refresh' to a short interval (the shortest is 5s, I believe.)

[Here's the Kibana documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/index.html) - might help.